# Proguard: AssertionError on release build

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to apply Proguard to my release app but so far, I have been getting an error. The debug built works perfectly:

```
04-06 20:25:17.689 544-544/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: com.myapp, PID: 544
                                                         java.lang.AssertionError
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.r.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.q$19.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k$1.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k$1.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.b.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.google.b.f.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.myapp.activities.bj.onResume(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.ae.f(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.ae.g(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.ae.b(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.app.ah.finishUpdate(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(
```

I have already added the rules below to my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
#for support library
# support design
-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

#Support v7
# Hide warnings about references to newer platforms in the library
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
# don't process support library
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

#Support v4
# Hide warnings about references to newer platforms in the library
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
# don't process support library
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
```

I don't know what to do - the error description is not really telling so I don't know where the assertionError comes from.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm quite new to Proguard but figured out the answer after investigating. I read this website that you can de-obfuscated the stacktrace as the stacktrace was obfuscated - that's why you see the a.a.a or b.b.b etc.: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

For mac, you will need to navigate to this folder:

```
sdk/tools/proguard/bin/
```

You will see the retrace.sh script within. You will now need to find the mapping.txt file within your folder here:

```
app/build/outputs/mapping/release/
```

Copy it to the bin folder where the sh is situated. Then you will need to copy the portion of the stacktrace you want to de-obfuscated and paste it into a text file and put it into the bin folder.

Use the following command to de-obfuscated in your terminal:

```
sh retrace.sh -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt > deobfuscated_trace.txt
```

Open `deobfuscated_trace.txt` and you will find that the error actually points to GSON. I fixed it by importing the proguard rules for GSON.

To check that proguard runned correctly, you will see the logs will now look like this:

```
04-06 21:20:15.453 6853-6853/com.myapp E/y: last vis 3
04-06 21:20:15.463 6853-6853/com.myapp E/y: last vis 3
04-06 21:20:15.480 6853-6853/com.myapp E/y: last vis 3
```

You can see that the class names have now been obfuscated, previously it would have been:

```
   04-06 21:20:15.453 6853-6853/com.myapp E/MyFragment: last vis 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding these lines in proguard.txt file should help.

```
-dontwarn com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.** { *; }
```